# readlink in cygwin

Tags: bash, cygwin

I do the most basic thing in every script

```
  SCRIPT=`readlink -f ${0}`
  HOME=`dirname $SCRIPT`
```

and, given `$0 = C:\Users\dir\file`, `readlink` gives me `/cygdrive/c/CURRENT_DIRECTORY/C:\Users\dir\file` so that the next `dirname` produces terrible `/cygdrive/c/Users/CURRENT_DIRECTORY/C:\Users\dir` instead of `C:\Users\dir` or `/cygdrive/c/Users/dir`

Is it supposed to work this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that I have found the answer: we should convert `$0` into cygwin format then `readlink` can work with it

```
ZERO=`cygpath ${0}`
SCRIPT=`readlink -f ${ZERO}`
```

Answer (score 2):

readlink in cygwin (Windows 7) is driving me crazy.  The same code works, then doesn't work, from moment to moment, with no changes to the input data. Mostly it doesn't work now (May 2013). It worked in January 2013.

```
$ ln -s foo bar
$ perl -e 'print readlink("/cygdrive/C/bin/bar")'
foo
```

but try that in a running program and it doesn't always work. readlink(`cygpath $file`) worked the first time I ran it, but on immediately re-running the program, it could no longer read the same $file and returned undef.

I'm currently using this horrible kludge.  It works, but I hate it:

```
if (-l $file) {
    my $real = readlink($file);
    if (!$real) {
         # KLUDGE FOR CYGWIN
         my $cmd = "perl -e 'print readlink(\"$file\")'";
         $real = `$cmd`;
         die "ERR: No link for link $file date=$fileDate" unless $real;
```

Comment: I have this same exact issue...readlink is only working intermittently when inside a shell script, but seems to always work when run directly from a Cygwin terminal. Did you ever figure out a workaround or what the issue was?

Comment: Still have this issue on some win7, readlink fails in some folders.